# retrieve last value from table in linq Extention method and bind with DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq

I am working on windows Form App. I want to retrieve last record from database and bind it with datagridview, I can get all value from this

```
var query2 = _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductInfos, c => c.Id, a => a.ProductId, (a, c) => new
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            ItemName = a.ItemName,
            CategoryName = a.Category.CategoryName,
            UnitName = a.Unit.UnitName,
            UnitValue = a.UnitSize,
            Quantity = a.Quantity,
            CostPrice = c.PurchasePrice,
            SalePrice = c.SalePrice,
            EntryDate = c.EntryDate,
            ExpireDate = c.ExpireDate
        }).toList();

        StockListGrid.DataSource = query2;
```

but i only want the last inserted value, i use

```
var query2 = _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductInfos, c => c.Id, a => a.ProductId, (a, c) => new
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            ItemName = a.ItemName,
            CategoryName = a.Category.CategoryName,
            UnitName = a.Unit.UnitName,
            UnitValue = a.UnitSize,
            Quantity = a.Quantity,
            CostPrice = c.PurchasePrice,
            SalePrice = c.SalePrice,
            EntryDate = c.EntryDate,
            ExpireDate = c.ExpireDate
        }).ToList().LastOrDefault();

        StockListGrid.DataSource = query2;
```

but this time i get no value.Please tell me how can i retrieve last inserted value?

Comment: If `Id` is an identity column, you can order by Id descending, then take top 1.

Comment: What you mean by _but this time i get no value_? `.LastOrDefault()` will return an object, not a collection of objects. Try `query.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).Take(1).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using OrderByDescending

```
var query2 = _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductInfos, c => c.Id, a => a.ProductId, (a, c) => new
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        ItemName = a.ItemName,
        CategoryName = a.Category.CategoryName,
        UnitName = a.Unit.UnitName,
        UnitValue = a.UnitSize,
        Quantity = a.Quantity,
        CostPrice = c.PurchasePrice,
        SalePrice = c.SalePrice,
        EntryDate = c.EntryDate,
        ExpireDate = c.ExpireDate
    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();
```

Or Max

```
var query2 = _context.Products.Join(_context.ProductInfos, c => c.Id, a => a.ProductId, (a, c) => new
{
    Id = a.Id,
    ItemName = a.ItemName,
    CategoryName = a.Category.CategoryName,
    UnitName = a.Unit.UnitName,
    UnitValue = a.UnitSize,
    Quantity = a.Quantity,
    CostPrice = c.PurchasePrice,
    SalePrice = c.SalePrice,
    EntryDate = c.EntryDate,
    ExpireDate = c.ExpireDate
}).Max(x => x.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your first query is a List<...>, all elements are of the same anonymous type `Anonymous1`. The type of your later query is one object of class `Anonymous1`. What does your `StockListGrid.DataSource` expect? A list or one single object?

`ToList` transports all elements from your Database management system (DBMS) to your local memory, after which you decide that you only want the last element

I see two problems

- Why transport all elements if you only want the last one?
- Is the last element of your joinresult defined? Is it the one with the highest `Id`? Or maybe the one with alphabetically last `ItemName`? Is it the one with the highest `SalePrice`?

Unfortunately Entity Framework does not support LastOrDefault. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ methods (linq to entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

The trick around this would be sorting in ascending order by the property you consider last and then take the `FirstOrDefault`. Keep in mind that (depending on your sort property) there might be several items with the same sort value, so a second sort is needed

```
var result = dbContext.Products.Join(dbContext.ProductInfos, ...)
    .OrderByDescending(joinResult => joinResult.SalePrice) // depending on your definition of Last

    .ThenByDescending(joinResult => joinResult.Id)         // in case there are two with same price
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is much more efficient, because only one element is transported from your DBMS to your local memory.

Note that the result is only one element, not a List. If you want assign a `List` with only this last element to your `DataSource`

```
.ThenByDescending(joinResult => joinResult.Id)  
.Take(1)
.ToList();
```

Again, only one anonymous object is transported